# Complexity of a method checking whether all characters in the string are unique

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, big-o

I am trying to write a function in kotlin that checks if all characters in the string are unique.

```kotlin
fun isUnique(s: String): Boolean {
     return s.filter {
          char -> s.count(char) == 1
     } == s
}
```

I would like to know what is the runtime complexity of this method. Is it O(n) or O(n pow2) (because we touch each char twice in the filter function and in the count function)?
Also is the space complexity O(1)?

Alternatively, I wrote this method

```kotlin
fun isUnique2(s: String): Boolean {
    return s.groupBy {
        char -> s.count(char)
    }.filterKeys{key > 1}.isEmpty()
}
```

what are the space and time complexity of this method?

I appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: For the first method, if `count` is `O(n)` then it would be `O(n^2)` because for every element, you're performing `O(n)` operations. In regards to the space complexity, you might want to have a look at what the `filter` method does and whether it allocates any new objects (hint: it does). For the second example, what do you think?

Comment: Also I would add that all these methods are very inefficient, so if you're looking to write something performant instead of idiomatic, you probably shouldn't be approaching it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implementation is O(n^2), not simply because you touch each char twice (it's actually 4 times because of `==`, but could be just twice if you compared sizes instead), but because for *each* char you consider in the filter, you iterate the whole N characters of the string via `count()`.

It's not the same to iterate the string twice, and to iterate the string *once per char* of the string. This is the difference between O(2n) (= O(n)) and O(n^2).

This first implementation also allocates an extra collection with filtered elements, which in the worst case contains all chars, so O(n) space.

The second implementation does even more work, you still start with an O(n^2) step because you `count` through the *whole* string to build *each* group. But then you add more space complexity because you allocate more intermediate collections.

You can have an O(n) solution, with O(n) space by simply turning your string into a `Set` and comparing sizes:

```kotlin
fun isUnique(s: String): Boolean {
     return s.toSet().size == s.length
}
```

Internally, `toSet()` uses a `LinkedHashSet`, for which insertion has an amortized cost of O(1). This means the string is iterated only once, and each char is inserted in O(1) into the set, which ensures at insertion time that there are no duplicates. Comparing sizes is also O(1) in general because most collections have a constant-cost way to access their size.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Both implementations have O(n^2) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

With the following solution you can have O(n) time complexity (keeping O(n) space) in the worst case:

```
fun isUnique(s: String): Boolean {
    val hashset = hashSetOf<Char>()
    return s.all { hashset.add(it)  }
}
```

But generally this algorithm may end up (returning `false`) before reaching end of the string (if we met some repeating char, no need to check remaining chars), so in the best case it may end on the 2-nd iteration.

The magic behind this consists of two parts:

1. `add` method of `Set` returns `false` if this set already contained the specified element
2. `all` method returns `false` on the first predicate, which evaluated to `false`

Comment: That's a nice trick to enable quick escapes :)

Comment: thank you for the suggested (much more efficient) solution.